# Как span элемент поместить в середину родительского блока?

Tags: css

[image: Пример]

Как выставить элемент before (иконка svg) по центру родительсокого блока?
Пробовал задать в процентах, но иконка двигается относительного общего серого блока, а не блока li.

Comment: Задать родителю `position: relative;`

Comment: Большое спасибо! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как отцентровать иконку относительно родителя.

Comment: `left: 50%; margin-left: -25px; ` в margin-left указать половину ширины иконки

Comment: Благодарю! Вы можете опубликовать ответ.

Comment: Я не пишу это как ответ, потому, что не считаю, что данный вопрос будет полезен для сообщества т.к. это базовый html/css. Ответа заслуживают вопросы, которые решают частые проблемы многих программистов. В данном случае нужна просто подсказка по азам одному человеку.  Если Александру по приколу то пусть оформляет код.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Оформил ответ в код, если [@Рашен Беар](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/212578/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B0%D1%80) выложит свой вариант -- удалю.

```css
.parent{
  width:800px;
  height:500px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  position:absolute;
}
li{
  list-style-type:none;
  height:300px;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 30%;
  position:relative;
}
li:before{
  content:'';
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  display:block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  top:50%;
  margin-top:-25px;
  left:50%;
  margin-left: -25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <li></li>
</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю! Удалять не нужно будет, будут ставить флажки вверх, это тоже будет прибавлять репутацию.